# How do I postpone processing of a Ruby on Rails route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I have a Ruby on Rails route; `config/routes.rb` says:

```
post 'upload/testruns' => 'upload#testruns'
```

In `app/controllers/api/upload_controller.rb` I have a:

```
def testruns
```

method, which handles the `POST`. The problem is that the method process time will increase as upload data accumulates because of the associated computations it requires (e.g. keeping statistics, recalculating them with every upload, etc).

This blocks the other side (i.e. the one initiating the `POST` to https://app.com/upload/testruns) and it will eventually hit its hardcoded timeout. I can totally increase the timeout, but it's a game of cat and mouse, soon one will need to be increased again and again.

How can I return from the testruns handling method immediately after I received the `POST` (which should be mere seconds) and delay the e.g. statistics processing for later?

The data being POSTed is not big; it's the accumulated history that makes it for an increasingly lengthy process.

Comment: use background jobs `activejob` or individually `sidekiq` `resque` will make all processing inbackground and send quick response with job id so response time will be less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a job usign ActiveJobs by running:

```
rails generate job test_runs
```

Edit Job

```
class TestRunJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(params)
    # Do you the stuff you need to do with your params
  end
end
```

And in your controller, start the job. This allows ActiveJob to run without getting in the way of sending back a response to your client (pass in your parameters & arguments):

```
class Upload < ActionController
  def testruns
    # Initiate Job
    TestRunJob.perform_later(params)

    # Respond to client immediately
    render plain: "Doing the stuff, continue on now"
  end
end
```

You can also use whichever background job service you want by installing the gem and configuring the adapter in your application.rb:

```
# config/application.rb
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
  end
end
```